# Why do I get terrible static in my phone mic / recording when my phone is charging from the mains?

Tags: mains, static

I live in an apartment block in the UK. When I record my voice into my phone's voice app when the phone is charging from the mains, I get a terrible constant static sound that is not present when the phone is not plugged in. I suspect that the static gets much worse when my neighbour is using their washing machine.

Is there anything I can do about this? Is it harmful to my phone or to any other appliance like a laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: Borrow a friend's phone, one that is completely different, and try the same thing. The results are cheap and quick and will help you narrow your focus a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, I am in the process of charging an old phone for comparison. In the meantime, though, I can observe that the amount of static varies widely. Earlier today it was comparatively quiet, then a few minutes later it was much louder, suggesting at least that something in the power supply is affecting the volume of static, and that it's not purely a fault with the phone?

Comment: Can you put up a record of the noise?

Comment: @jonk Your suggestion was a good one. I switched to my old phone, using the same voice app and I get no noise even while charging.This backs up what loudnoises is saying below.

Comment: Chargers are getting pretty annoying now, including a capacitor bridging across primary and secondary and I've been feeling definite tingling voltages as a result. On my Microsoft surface book, I measured 16 vac on the case! And it affected my use of their pen device, too. Fix is to reverse the plug. But a two month support issue I raised finally had them admit the issue while claiming it is intended and safe.

Comment: Put a ferrite on the charging cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described it sounds like your phone charger is carrying a lot of noise from the mains to your phone.

1. Noise on your power source can come from a variety of causes, for example the one you have listed in your question: a washing machine. Electro-mechanical systems that take a lot of power are difficult to regulate, and can thus push noise back on to the mains voltage.
2. AC-DC converters then typically try to remove this noise in the form of **filtering**, but some are made better than others.
3. Again, your phone will probably be filtering the DC that is supplied, but in this case it sounds as though it is not filtering it sufficiently and is actually letting it effect other subcircuits, in this case your microphone circuit. Microphones (I'm presuming an analogue mic) are very **sensitive to noise** as the signal they produce are very low amplitude.

When you are just on your battery the noise will not be present as batteries are generally very quiet power supplies.

The noise shouldn't be damaging, but if you are very concerned there are additional filters you can get in the form of power strips that could reduce this issue.